# How do I override a single JavaScript file used in a library?

Tags: javascript, 9

I am trying to override the Search API autocomplete JavaScript file.
In mytheme.libraries, I added the following lines.

```yaml
mytheme_autocomplete:
  js:
    'assets/js/autocomplete.js': { }
```

In mytheme.info, I added the following lines.

```yaml
libraries-override:
  search_api_autocomplete/search_api_autocomplete:
    js:
      component:
        js/search_api_autocomplete.js: mytheme_autocomplete
```

When I visit the site, js/search_api_autocomplete.js is still loaded, while assets/js/autocomplete.js isn't loaded.

How do I override a single JavaScript file used in a library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're overriding a single js file, you need to specify a file, not a library:

```
libraries-override:
  search_api_autocomplete/search_api_autocomplete:
    js:
      js/search_api_autocomplete.js: assets/js/autocomplete.js
```

However, specify your theme's library if you intend to override an entire library:

```
libraries-override:
  search_api_autocomplete/search_api_autocomplete: mytheme/mytheme_autocomplete
```

See the [Overriding and extending libraries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#override-extend) documentation on d.o

Comment: Thanks, I was able to override the whole library using your 2nd example, but could not override the single JS file in your first example/

Comment: I believe you may have added the extra "component" layer in the overrides definition. That should not be there as the search_api_autocomplete library does not specific the javascript that way. I updated the example with something that should work with that file.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the component / theme / base, etc weights only apply to css files, not js files, i.e. js would never have component in its definition hierarchy. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843#library